# Find the most advantageous sequence of currency exchange

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am working with the following exercise from my book:

Shortest path algorithms can be applied in currency trading. Let c<sub>1</sub> , c<sub>2</sub> , . . . , c<sub>n</sub> be various currencies; for instance, c<sub>1</sub> might be dollars, c<sub>2</sub> pounds, and c<sub>3</sub> lire. For any two currencies c<sub>i</sub> and
c<sub>j</sub>, there is an exchange rate r<sub>i,j</sub>; this means that you can purchase r<sub>i,j</sub> units of currency c<sub>j</sub> in
exchange for one unit of c<sub>i</sub>. These exchange rates satisfy the condition that r<sub>i,j</sub> · r<sub>j,i</sub> < 1, so that if
you start with a unit of currency c<sub>i</sub>, change it into currency c<sub>j</sub> and then convert back to currency
c<sub>i</sub>, you end up with less than one unit of currency c<sub>i</sub> (the difference is the cost of the transaction).
(a) Give an efficient algorithm for the following problem: Given a set of exchange rates r<sub>i,j</sub>,
and two currencies s and t, find the most advantageous sequence of currency exchanges for
converting currency s into currency t. Toward this goal, you should represent the currencies
and rates by a graph whose edge lengths are real numbers.

---

So what basically we want to do is instead of minimizing, we need to maximize the profit. Therefore we need to find the longest path from s to t. We are asserted of the existence of the shortest path from s to t.

The way I thought to solve this problem is following this algorithm:

1. Negate all the edges of the graph
2. Run the shortest path algorithm for directed acyclic graphs.

I believe this would work but I am not sure. On google I found some solutions that include another step: converting the multiplication of the rates to additions using logarithms. I think this step is not necessary her e but still I am not sure.